# Current trigger and class is creating line items when it is not expected

Tags: apex, trigger, class

Currently I have trigger which add line items to the credit request.  Each line items has a qty field which is multiplied by QTY in the credit request object.

This is the multiplier field.  This works as long as QTY has a value.  If I attempt to create a credit request with QTY 0, line are added to the request when they shouldn't be.

I believe this is due to using a custom setting definition.  The customer setting definition has productid, qty, and multiplier field.  Not all products need a value in the multiplier field since their qty is the always the same.  These are the products that create credit lines even when the high level QTY is 0.

Need help to address the logic in the following code to prevent these from being created when QTY is 0.  QTY field is used in the multiplier field for some products.

```
public class AddOrUpdateCreditLineTriggerHandler {

Map<Id, List<Credit_lines__c>> mapCRToCL = new Map<id, List<credit_lines__c>>();
map<id, Credit_Request__c> original; 
map<id,Credit_Request__c> modified;
List<Credit_Lines__c> associatedCreditLines;
List<Credit_lines__c> toDelete = new List<Credit_Lines__c>();
List<Credit_lines__c> toInsert = new List<Credit_lines__c>();

public AddOrUpdateCreditLineTriggerHandler(List<Credit_Request__c> original, List<Credit_Request__c> modified){
    if(original != null) {
        this.original = New Map<Id, Credit_Request__C>(original);
    }
    this.modified = New Map<Id, Credit_Request__c>(modified);
    associatedCreditLines = 
        [SELECT id, Product__C, Name, credit_request__c 
        FROM Credit_Lines__C 
        WHERE Credit_request__c in :modified ];
    for(Credit_lines__c cl: associatedCreditLines) {
        if(mapCRToCL.containsKey(cl.credit_request__c)){
            mapCRToCL.get(cl.credit_request__c).add(cl);
        } else {
            mapCRToCL.put(cl.credit_request__c, new List<Credit_Lines__c>{cl}); 
        }
    }
}

public void run(){ 
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        afterInsert();
    } else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
        afterUpdate();
    }
}

private void afterInsert(){
    for(Credit_Request__c cr : this.modified.values() ){
        toInsert.addAll(createStandardCreditLines(cr));
    }
    insert toInsert;
}

private void afterUpdate(){
    for(Credit_Request__c cr : filterQtyChanged(this.modified.values())){
        toDelete.addAll(mapCRToCl.get(cr.id));
        toInsert.addAll(createStandardCreditLines(cr));
    }
   delete toDelete;
   insert toInsert;
}

private List<Credit_lines__c> createStandardCreditLines(Credit_Request__c cr){
    List<Credit_Lines__c> created = new List<Credit_Lines__c>();
    for(AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c a: creditLines()){
        if(a.multiplierField__c != null && cr.get(a.multiplierField__c) == null){
            continue;
        }
        Double multiplier = 1;
        if(a.multiplierField__c != null && cr.get(a.multiplierField__c) != null){
            multiplier = (Double) cr.get(a.multiplierField__c);
        }
        created.add(
            New Credit_lines__c(
                Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                Quantity__c = (a.Qty__c * multiplier),
                Product__c = a.productId__c
            )
        );
    }
    return created;
}

private List<AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c> CreditLines(){
    return AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c.getall().values();
}   

private List<Credit_Request__c> filterQtyChanged(List<Credit_Request__c> possible){
    List<Credit_request__c> toUpdate = new List<Credit_Request__c>();
    for(Credit_Request__c cr : this.modified.values()){ 
        if(QuantityChanged(this.original.get(cr.id), cr)){
            toUpdate.add(cr);
        }
    }
    return toUpdate;
}

// Helper methods
private Boolean QuantityChanged(Credit_Request__c original, Credit_Request__c modified){
    return (original.RS_cell_qty__c != modified.RS_Cell_Qty__c) || 
        (original.SEQUEL_cell_qty__c != modified.Sequel_cell_qty__c);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it will work, but according to your question, you want to create Credit Request if quantity>0, so you need to add this condition before creation.

```
private List<Credit_lines__c> createStandardCreditLines(Credit_Request__c cr){
    List<Credit_Lines__c> created = new List<Credit_Lines__c>();
    for(AutomatedCreditLineRecords__c a: creditLines())
    {
        if(a.multiplierField__c != null && cr.get(a.multiplierField__c) == null){
            continue;
        }
        Double multiplier = 1;
        if(a.multiplierField__c != null && cr.get(a.multiplierField__c) != null){
            multiplier = (Double) cr.get(a.multiplierField__c);
        }
        if(a.Qty__c>0 && a.multiplierField__c>1)
        {
            created.add(
                New Credit_lines__c(
                    Credit_Request__c = cr.Id,
                    Quantity__c = (a.Qty__c * multiplier),
                    Product__c = a.productId__c
                )
            );
        }

    }
    return created;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for the the following if a.multiplierField__c<1, then the credit request will be created without the addition of credit line items.

Comment: so you need to add that condition like this: if(a.Qty__c>0 && a.multiplierField__c>1)

Comment: Thanks, but when I add a.multiplierField__c==null, I would like the loop to end and just return created.  Currently it does not work with null.  Looking for guidelines on how to state if multiplier field is 0 than do not add credit lines, but complete

Comment: you have to debug properly and check why it is happening